# how to delete temp files (clean up) generated by a java program?

Tags: java, portable-executable, portable-applications

I am working on a portable java app that generates some files on the fly on the user's PC (windows xp). Now, what I want is to delete those temp files after the java program's exit. Obviously, java's file deletion mechanism can not be trusted. Even if I mark a file as to be deleted on exit (file.deleteOnExit() ) , most of the times it is not deleted.  I use a wrapper (java2exe) to run it as an executable. Any suggestions or solutions are welcome ?

Thanks,
Deep

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that the reason that `deleteOnExit` is failing is because your application still has the files open when your application exits.  This will cause the delete to fail on Windows due to lingering file locks.

The solution is to close all streams for your temporary files before you exit.

Comment: Yes but the thing is user opens those files using system default file applications (e.g. acrobat for pdf files, IE for html files) and if the files are open when the application exits then there is no way to close the files. Is there any sleek solution to this problem ?

Comment: If the files are opened by some external application, you've got a real problem.  For a start, the Java application probably shouldn't be *trying* to delete them until the external app has exited.